# Solr exiting atfter multiple posts

Tags: tomcat, solr

I am facing problems doing some imports to solr.

The setup is as follows:

- Solr Node Standalone
- 90 Cores
- Approx. 500 URLs per core

The Import process:

- Worker fetches a list of all cores from database
- List item has list of domains by core from database
- split into chunks of 20 URLs per chunk
- import the chunk via post tool. All urls at once
- perform commit via rest
- after all chunks of current core are finished **optimize** is called
- proceed with next core

After approx. one hour solr quits working. The admin interface is not reachable any more and search requests fail.

When I restart solr it work again - until the next exit...

As I'm on the iPad now I can't paste any logs - but maybe someone has an idea or knows the problem of "large" batch imports.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of Solr? The Solr log would be important to diagnose anything like this. What's a "reorganise" (an optimize?) ?

Comment: Altes Version. You're right I meant optimize.

Comment: What does "Altes Version" mean? (old version? which version? have you tried upgrading to a newer version and newer jvm?)

Comment: Latest. It was too late to write:)

Comment: shouldn't be any problems with batch in principle, please provide logs